# Where is denyhosts WORK_DIR in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, denyhosts

I'm trying to configure my denyhosts on my server and I read in it's [FAQ's entry on *How can I prevent a legitimate IP address from being blocked by DenyHosts?*](http://denyhost.sourceforge.net/faq.php#3_7) that I have to move to `WORK_DIR`.

I don't know where `WORK_DIR` is? Does anyone know where is it?

Also I added my IP to hosts.allow like this:

```
ALL: 12.345.467.89
```

Is it enough?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

WORK_DIR is a variable that is defined in your `denyhosts.cfg`.

Default values I have seen are:

1. `/usr/share/denyhosts/data`.
2. `/var/lib/denyhosts`.

Check your `denyhosts.cfg` to be certain but it's probably one of those two.

[edit] On Ubuntu 14.04 you should look in the file /etc/denyhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

WORK-DIR should be the directory you want to add access for.

Comment: And where it's located?

Comment: DenyHosts does not control access to *directories*.  It controls access to *hosts*.  This answer does not make sense as written.